# Not able to use handler properly in Android

Tags: java, android

I am learning the android development which now I am making a simple timer which I needs a handler to keep it running. If I put the handler inside the main activity, everything goods but I would like to put the method outside the main activity so I can reuse the codes and should be more flexible if I would like to change anything.

here is my code:

```
*public class Timer{

    public void runTimer(TextView view, int seconds, boolean running){
        TextView timerTextView = (TextView) view;
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        MyRunnable r = new MyRunnable(handler,view,seconds,running);
        handler.post(r);

    }



}

class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private TextView view;
    private int seconds;
    private boolean running;
    private Handler handler;

    public MyRunnable(Handler handler, TextView view, int seconds, boolean running){
        this.handler= handler;
        this.view =view;
        this.seconds = seconds;
        this.running = running;
    }

    public void run(){
        TextView timerTextView = (TextView) view;
        int hours = seconds/3600;
        int minutes = (seconds%3600)/60;
        int secs = seconds%60;
        String time = String.format("%d:%02d:%02d",hours,minutes,secs);
        timerTextView.setText(time);
        if (running){
            seconds++;
        }
        handler.postDelayed(this,100);
    }

}*
```

And I created an object in the main activity to call this function. The app can run but the timer doesn't work properly. It only runs the first time but then stop at all. It doesn't keep running. Do you know where is the problem? thanks for your help first!

Main code:

```
*package com.mad.chapter4;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class StopWatchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Timer timer = new Timer();


    private int seconds = 0;
    private boolean running = false;
    private boolean wasRunning;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stop_watch);
        TextView ttv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerTextView);

            if(savedInstanceState!=null){
                seconds = savedInstanceState.getInt("seconds");
                running = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("running");
                wasRunning = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("wasRunning");
            }

        seconds = timer.runTimer(ttv,seconds,running);
    }

    public void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        savedInstanceState.putInt("seconds",seconds);
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean("running",running);
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean("wasRunning",wasRunning);
    }

    protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        wasRunning = running;
        running = false;
    }

    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        if(wasRunning){
            running = true;
        }
    }



    public void onClickStartButton(View view){
        running = true;
    }

    public void onClickStopButton (View view){
        running = false;
    }

    public void onClickResetButton (View view){
        seconds = 0;
        running = false;
    }



//    public void runTimer(){
//
//        final TextView timerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerTextView);
//        final Handler handler = new Handler();
//
//        Runnable r = new Runnable(){
//            @Override
//            public void run(){
//                int hours = seconds/3600;
//                int minutes = (seconds%3600)/60;
//                int secs = seconds%60;
//                String time = String.format("%d:%02d:%02d",hours,minutes,secs);
//                timerTextView.setText(time);
//                if (running){
//                    seconds++;
//                }
//                handler.postDelayed(this,100);
//            }
//        };
//
//        handler.post(r);
//
//
//    }


}*
```

Comment: your code is working fine, could you please post your main activity code also?

Comment: Thanks and here is my main code:

Comment: @HoMingTam: please add any additional code to the question, rather than in comments.

Comment: @halfer just did it, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

From the way I see it your `running` and `wasRunning` are never set to true which in turn is not updating your UI only first time but not after that. Try setting `running` and `wasRunning` to true before you call `timer.runTimer(ttv, seconds, running)` in onCreate. I think when you were calling this code in activity you were making call to `onClickStartButton(View view)` which did set the `running` flag to true and was updating your UI correctly.

Also, your `runTimer` functions does not return anything but you in your code you are assigning this function result to an int. Is that a copy/paste error?

Comment: I have tried your code without flags `running` and `wasRunning` and it is working for me. Can you please try with `timer.runTimer(ttv, seconds, true)`

Comment: Yes! Thanks and the timer starts running now. But it is kept running and I can't use the buttons to control it. Trying to put the timer.runtimer(ttv,seconds,true) in each method but it doesn't work, any idea?